# How to update the ActivityParty of an existing appointment using dynamics 365 webapi v9.0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I would like to update the ActivityParty of an already existing appointment in dynamics 365 9.0 using the webapi v9.0. My goal is to update the required attendees and the optional attendees field.

I am trying to create a PUT request as described in the documentation of the webapi under *Associate entities on update using collection-valued navigation property*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api#associate-entities-on-update-using-collection-valued-navigation-property

Below you find the code i am using:

```js
var activity = {};
var parties = [];

var requiredAttendee = {};
requiredAttendee["partyid_lead@odata.bind"] = "/leads(3fcc8c7b-e38d-e911-90f8-005056879361)";
requiredAttendee["participationtypemask"] = 5;

var optionalAttendee = {};
optionalAttendee["partyid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(2e1261de-77cf-4f9b-a1bb-ff3a1f5a4add)";
optionalAttendee["participationtypemask"] = 6;

parties.push(requiredAttendee);
parties.push(optionalAttendee);

activity["value"] = parties;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
           req.open("PUT", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/appointments(20064d15-728e-e911-90f8-005056879361)/appointment_activity_parties", true);
           req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
           req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
           req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
           req.onreadystatechange = function () {
               if (this.readyState === 4) {
                   req.onreadystatechange = null;
                   if (this.status === 204) {
                   } else {
                       Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                   }
               }
           };
           req.send(JSON.stringify(activity));
```

I would expect that the request is successful. However i get a Bad Request with the following error message:

An error occurred while validating input parameters: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceWrapper' to type 'System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataNestedResourceInfoWrapper'.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same issue. I changed the required attendees in the UI on a Unified Interface page and took a look at the network tab after saving. It looks like it does a Reschedule request despite the fact that the date/time of the appointment wasn't changing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/reschedule

The request body looks like this:

```json
{
    "Target": {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.appointment",
        "subject": "Test",
        "appointment_activity_parties": [
            {
                "partyid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(F722E432-2185-EC11-8D21-000D3A5ADF30)",
                "participationtypemask": 5
            },
            {
                "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "/systemusers(3CE09FD4-7EA7-E711-A94D-000D3A37D006)",
                "participationtypemask": 7
            }
        ],
        "isalldayevent": false,
        "activityid": "{E83124B1-77AB-EC11-983F-0022480B6627}"
    },
    "ReturnNotifications": true
}
```